# What’s the correct URL for placing a call on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is the code for calling on the iPhone automatically

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:11111111111"]]);
```

Comment: I have only ipodtouch and iPad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second line is fine and will work.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://1111111111"]]);
```

Comment: As a comment, if the number has any spaces.. it won't call.

Answer (score 4):

From trying on an iPhone, `tel://123456789` is the way to go. The `tel:123456789` option is not even recognized, at least by the Safari URL bar.

Answer (score 4):

you can only call from Iphone device not from ipad/ipod, and you can dial number from iphone like bellow code:-

```
NSString *value=@"your number";
NSURL *url = [[ NSURL alloc ] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",value]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: Remove the `//` from `tel:` they are not in the [tel URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007893-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

**Too many answers with conflicting comments.**

*(slash, no slash, semicolumn, tel, telprompt ?)*

**Swift**, one size fits all:

```swift
if let phoneURL = NSURL(string: "telprompt:\(phoneNumber)") {
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(phoneURL) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(phoneURL)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SwiftArchitect's answer doesn't fit all.
I wanted to actually initiate an automatic call, not prompt.

So there is a difference between tel and telprompt.

`tel:` actually initiates the call.

```
if let url = URL(string: "tel:\(phoneNumber)") {
  if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
  }
}
```

`telprompt:` prompts for call or cancel.

```
if let url = URL(string: "telprompt:\(phoneNumber)") {
  if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
  }
}
```

I didn't know the difference. Question also asks for calling. So this kind of answer would have helped me save time.