# How to call a phone number from ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to call a phone number from ios app using:
It's not working, although the method gets called:

```
-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {

        NSString *phoneCallNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",listingPhoneNumber ];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneCallNum]];

        NSLog(@"phone btn touch %@", phoneCallNum);
    }
```

`NSLog` output: phone btn touch tel://+39 0668806972

Comment: please check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306293/whats-the-correct-url-for-placing-a-call-on-an-iphone/13306894#13306894

Comment: also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582327/how-to-make-a-call-programmatically

Comment: Checkout _Native app URL string_ bullet: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1

Answer (score 89, accepted):

your code is correct. did you check in real device. this function will not work in simulator.

try this also,

```
NSString *phNo = @"+919876543210";
NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@",phNo]];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneUrl]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneUrl];
    } else
    {
        calert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Call facility is not available!!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [calert show];
    }
```

** Swift 3 version**

```
if let url = URL(string: "telprompt:\(phoneNumber)") {
  if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(call, options: []) { result in
       // do something with result
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I tried with the phone number you provided and it works. perhaps it's my phone number formatting. With mine I get "Call facility is not available!!!" could my number be off because of the + as in: +39 0668806972

Comment: my problem was the whitespace that I stripped out. then it worked. thanks!

Comment: `telprompt:` is not official and it may be both removed in future versions or your app may be rejected.

Comment: Hey you are missing // after telprompt:-----Should be telprompt:// . -1 for being careless. Took quite sometime for me to find the problem. :P

Answer (score 14):

Telephony does not work on simulators/iPod/iPad, you will require to run the app on an iPhone with active sim card.

Also the URL scheme to invoke the telephony application is `tel:<phone_number>`. Refer [Apple docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html)

Ideally, you should check if the device is having the telephony module and then perform the `openURL:` call. Use this code to perform the check,

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:callUrl]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:callUrl];
}
else {
    //Show error message to user, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use following method to make call:

```
 NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:number];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

Comment: Be aware that the `telprompt:` is not a official scheme and can therefor be removed from iOS in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below.

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:Number];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Remove the `//` from `tel:` they are not in the [tel URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007893-SW1)

Comment: I tried this and nothing happens. the method gets called along with the nslog output: phone btn touch tel:+39 0668806972

Comment: Are you testing on an iphone? caz this is the right code man.

Comment: @Manthan yes, testing on a device. I wonder if it's the format of my phone number. I tried +919876543210 and it works but then with +39 0668806972 it doesn't

Comment: Hmm so check out the formant its not correct then.

Comment: @Manthan remove the space perhaps?

Comment: try it may be thats what causing the problem for you.

Comment: my problem was the whitespace that I stripped out. then it worked. thanks!

Comment: Ohkk. then please and upvote it if my answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:@"9414481799"];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

This will only run on device.