# iOS: Strange error on phone call from App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, phone-call

In order to make a call from my app I used the following code:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"666666666";
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", phoneNumber];
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneUrl]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneUrl];
} else
{
    calert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Call facility is not available!!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [calert show];
}
```

Its working as expected, but im getting the following error on the Xcode console when I run it on an iPhone:

> ERROR:    [AVAudioSession Notify Thread] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:49:
>   ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port iPhone
>   Micr√≥fono (type: MicrophoneBuiltIn)

I searched for information about this error but I have not found anything to help me understand why is happening.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDITED with CanOpenURL: validation.

I also noticed that im getting the error on iPhone 5 with iOS 9.2 but not on iPhone 6 with iOS 8.2.

Comment: "its working as expected."  pls explain it. Where does it worked ?

Comment: I mean that although I see this error in Xcode console, the app makes the call.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18914346/767329 check this one, you should check if you can openURL before openURL call

Comment: Thanks, I added the validation but im getting the same error.

Comment: unless `AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:49` is not your code, this is probably a debug message from the OS or phone app.

Comment: Just a heads up, you should change your telephone format to `tel://`.

Comment: Thanks, but same issue on iPhone 5 running iOS 9.2