# Is it possible to make silent phone calling on iPhone by using application

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, object

I am working on such kind of application where i have to call a mobile no. or land line no. by application. i just want to know that apple allowed to make the silent calling is initiated by the application ?

Also is it possible to read the all sms of iPhone by using a application ?

Comment: You can call from application here are some examples,
[Click here 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914156/how-to-call-a-phone-number-from-ios-app) [Click here 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104883/making-a-call-programatically-from-iphone-app-and-returning-back-to-the-app-afte)

Answer (score 0):

When you will try to call Mobile number from application, it will open default call application and then you will not get any access.

Not possible to read all SMS of iPhone by using application.