# Prepare phone call from iOS app, without beginning the call

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

I'm trying to begin a phone call from within my iPhone app (similar to several [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306293/what-s-the-correct-url-for-placing-a-call-on-an-iphone) already answered on SO), but with a specific wrinkle: my boss *doesn't* want the call to begin immediately.  He wants the app to open the Phone app and autofill the number, but require the user to actually press the green button to begin the call.

Is this possible?  All the research I've been doing has followed the...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://911"]];
```

...pattern, which begins the call automatically as soon as it switches over.

Is it possible to prep the call and autofill the number, but not actually begin the call automatically?

Comment: "my boss doesn't want the call to begin immediately." It doesn't. An app can't place a phone call. The user *must* be the one who actually has to do something for the call to proceed. Unless I misunderstood, you made it should like you don't want the app to actually  make the call, but its not capable of doing that anyway.

Comment: @HerrErnstvonFlübbergrübber  What I meant was, currently when a user taps "call" in our app, it switches to the Phone app and *immediately* begins the call.  It's ringing before the app switch is even complete.  I'm hoping to have the user tap "call" in our app, and get switched over to the Phone app with the phone number filled in and ready to go, but then wait for the user to manually hit the green button to begin the call.

Comment: I don't think that is going to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know that is not possible. one thing you could do is for example present an alert and ask the user explicitly if he / she wants to make the call.