# How to call an extension after dialing a phone number in Swift

Tags: swift, phone-call

How would I call an extension after dialing a phone number?

This is how I make the call but I'm not really sure where to go from here.

```
@IBAction func phoneLaunch(sender: AnyObject) {
    callNumber("\(newArray[3])")
}
```

I don't know how to keep dialing numbers correctly after a phone number is called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What’s the correct URL for placing a call on an iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306293/what-s-the-correct-url-for-placing-a-call-on-an-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the issue, you just have to insert a comma in between the phone number and the extension.

```
@IBAction func phoneLaunch(sender: AnyObject) {
    callNumber("phoneNumber", extensionNum: "extensionNumber")
}

private func callNumber(phoneNumber:String, extensionNum:String) {
    if let phoneCallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber),\(extensionNum)") {
        let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
            application.openURL(phoneCallURL);
        }
    }
}
```